# How do I tell momentjs/moment-tz that the string I'm giving it is already in the timezone I'm giving it?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

Small problem that's driving me nuts. I'm getting a time as a string from an API call, and I'm getting the timezone the time is in, as two separate strings. I'm trying to create a moment that is using this given data and it's taking my local machine timezone as a starting point and adjusting into the given zone

```
let timeFromApi = "01 Jan 2021 15:00";             //That's 3pm, Eastern Standard Time
let timeZoneFromApi = "America/Indianapolis";     //Server says "time I gave is in EST"
```

If I do either of these, with my local machine set to UTC:

```
let x = moment.tz(timeFromApi, timeZoneFromApi).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss zz");
let y = moment(timeFromApi).tz(timeZoneFromApi).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss zz");
```

Then they both end up containing "2021-01-01 10:00 -05"..

Moment seems to assume the given string is in timezone the local machine is in: If I set the local machine to EST, then I get "2021-01-01 15:00 -05" like I expect...

... but I don't want moment reading the local machine time at all. I literally want to give it a time, and give it a timezone and have it create that time in that timezone - how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Having gone through the same sort of trouble, I can tell you that

```
let x = moment.tz(timeFromApi, timeZoneFromApi);
```

is the correct method.  The [documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) also says that is the way to do.  I suspect your trouble is the formatting not the parsing.  The `z` and `zz` formatting options are deprecated as of 1.6 (see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).  So I'd play with the formatting a bit.